# Make two arrays from and array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Assume that you have an array in php just like that:

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

do you know how i can make a subarray with the elements:

> "a","c","e"

and a subarray with:

> "b","d"

To be more specific i want to create two subarrays one with the odd indexes and one with the even indexes from the original array

Comment: use array_slice() for this

Comment: @saty slice won't do the trick...